# How to send emoji as part of HTTP-OUTPUT-PLUGIN for logstash to Telegram bot

Tags: logstash, telegram-bot, emoji

I want to send emoji as part of message from logstash using http-output-plugin to telegram bot and get it displayed in Telegram group. PFB the code being used. Please suggest.

```
http {
    format => "json"
    http_method => "post"
    url => "https://api.telegram.org:443/bot481032672:AAGhbY0l6cuy_HXA-SyiJHbwRznPdA3KPaQ/sendMessage"
    mapping => {
        "chat_id" => "-191360460"
        "text" => "Severity=%{SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.111.15.3.1.1.5.1}
        App Name=%{kpi_match_name}
        RUEI KPI Name=%{SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.111.15.3.1.1.14.1}
        Current Value=%{kpi_cur_value}"
    }
}
```

SY

Comment: What do you want us to suggest? Please the guide on asking good questions at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and [edit] your question accordingly to include the specific problem you're facing.

Comment: I am unable send emoji as part of http request to telegram api. even if use \ud83d\ude31\u26a0 as part of text it doesnt show in telegram chat group. it comes as plain string. I would wnat to know how to do that?

Comment: PLEASE IGNORE PREVIOUS COMMENT------ I am sending this \ud83d\ude31 as part of text it doesnt show emoji in telegram chat group. it is coming as plain string. I would want to know how to make sure it represents as emoji in chat group? @Capricorn

Answer (score 0):

You can send emojis through two ways: `\uXXXX` and `\U0000XXXX`. For example the emoji `U+1F601` the format would be `\u1F601`, but I recommend you use the another format `\U0001F601`. If the unicode format (`U+1F601`) after "+" has 5 characters you need to put 3 zeros `\U + 000 + 1F601 = \U0001F601`, but if the unicode format after "+" has 4 characters you need to put 4 zeros, for example `U+D83D` has to be `\U + 0000 + D83D = \U0000D83D`.

In this site you can get the unicode emojis that you need: https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html

Comment: Where should I add this particular format in code I have shared

Comment: You should add the emojis in the text. I guess this is the message text: `Severity=% {SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.111.15.3.1.1.5.1} App Name=%{kpi_match_name} RUEI KPI Name=%{SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.111.15.3.1.1.14.1} Current Value=%{kpi_cur_value}`, so if you can send a emoji, you should add in that message, for example: `Severity=% {SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.111.15.3.1.1.5.1} App Name=%{kpi_match_name} RUEI KPI Name=%{SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.111.15.3.1.1.14.1} Current Value=%{kpi_cur_value} \U0000D83D`.

Comment: Thanks @JersonJimenez +1

Comment: If the answer was useful, please put +1.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me.

1. Add

   parse_mode: "HTML"

to your "mapping" array. This would render the text as HTML.
See https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage for details.

2. Add emoji as "&#x1F622". You can find the list of codes here: https://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode